# The Soundcloud Stream URL returns an error code 401

Tags: audio, oauth, audio-streaming, soundcloud, http-status-code-401

This URL used to function well in my browser, but now it returns an error code of 401.

***URL:*** [https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/881102623/stream?client_id=fbb40e82698631328efb400b0700834f](https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/881102623/stream?client_id=fbb40e82698631328efb400b0700834d)

***Browser Response:***

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "A request must contain the Authorization header. For details please refer to https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/security-updates-api.",
  "link": "https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/explorer/open-api",
  "status": "401     - Unauthorized",
  "errors": [
    {
      "error_message": "A request must contain the Authorization header. For details please refer to https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/security-updates-api."
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

Please assist us in resolving this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [stream](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing) requires an authorization header.

```
# request a track you want to stream
$ curl -X GET "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TRACK_ID" \
       -H  "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
       -H "Authorization: OAuth ACCESS_TOKEN"

# extract stream_url when available from a response
$ curl -X GET "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TRACK_ID/stream" \
         -H  "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
         -H "Authorization: OAuth ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

You are getting `401 - Unauthorized` because you have not supplied an access token, with permissions to access track 881102623.

You should consult the [authentication guide](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication) on how to request an access token.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @DalmTo; but, I'm not sure where I may obtain an OAuth ACCESS TOKEN; could you assist me with this?

Comment: Follow the directions in the [authentication guide](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication) it will show you how to request an access token.  there are three steps to the Oauth2 process to request an access token. The documentation even shows how to refresh it when the access token expires.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo its working now... & now i am facing  {"code":429,"message":"rate_limit_exceeded","link":"https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/rate-limits#errors","status":"429 - Too Many Requests","errors":[{"error_message":"rate_limit_exceeded"}],"error":null,"error_code":"rate_limit_exceeded"}  my api request rate limit is exceeded how to increase that

Comment: well thats a nice error.  Means you are going to fast. Slow down your making to many requests and spamming the server.

Comment: Yes, I make too many requests in development. Now that I've utilised the token according to the expiration period, everything is working well. Thanks a lot, @DalmTo.

Comment: @Annamalai - can you provide the code you managed to get OAuth ACCESS TOKEN?

Comment: Yes Provided Refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672979/9596361

 @Toniq

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code now that I've fixed the Soundcloud Stream URL returning an error code 401. It is now fully operational.

```
<?php
        /* SOUNDCLOUD CREDENTIALS */
        $CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
        $CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';
    
    
        $trackId = 1142143435; /*Your Track Id*/
    
        $ACCESS_TOKEN = getOAuth($CLIENT_ID,$CLIENT_SECRET);
    
        $stream = streamURL($trackId, $ACCESS_TOKEN);
    
        $track_request = trackDetails($trackId, $ACCESS_TOKEN);
    
    
        function getOAuth($CLIENT_ID,$CLIENT_SECRET)
        {
            $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token";
    
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
            $headers = array(
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
            $data = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=".$CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=".$CLIENT_SECRET;
    
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    
            //for debug only!
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }
    
        function trackDetails($trackId, $ACCESS_TOKEN)
        {
            $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" . $trackId;
    
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
            $headers = array(
                "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Authorization: OAuth " . $ACCESS_TOKEN,
            );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            //for debug only!
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }
    
    
        function streamURL($trackId, $ACCESS_TOKEN)
        {
            $url = "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/".$trackId."/stream";
    
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
            $headers = array(
                "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Authorization: OAuth ".$ACCESS_TOKEN,
            );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            //for debug only!
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }
    ?>
```

I've included the curl responses from the preceding code here.

***For OAuth Token:***

```
{
  "access_token": "2-141361--bj15bZfizomSpwcfA5JX2ND",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "eP8P6FENUZ7WSGDIf3i1wvwGSwhHCfdx",
  "scope": "",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

***For Stream URL:***

Note: The generated Stream URL is only valid for one time; if you want another, you must generate a new one with an unexpired OAuth Token.

location - The Stream URL is the one you're looking for.

```
{
  "status": "302 - Found",
  "location": "https://cf-media.sndcdn.com/GTbktMIdZVGG.128.mp3?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiKjovL2NmLW1lZGlhLnNuZGNkbi5jb20vR1Ria3RNSWRaVkdHLjEyOC5tcDMqIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjM0ODg3MjU3fX19XX0_&Signature=OMu7AQogYzdQpi0O0gLYvgn9IFvS5yPzRPxjYafLDDdEyKNvUxS3~TIZPC7IKOnBs~TPubz7DT~DDXkOKEVlkBDy0TxHD1LLKD3DIhE6ze8dHYXCGzlaqPCvkQ-51kDIwu8EeUFi5byK0X3UJqZ057AXhxX~qF9f5h~~5~LRbPR6ARcyWV97A-SeqZYugU6QA2T9G~JWF3fO3gLETWwplPuF0QhDARz~AIZ0AEG6xGWo6FhOPEMiBHJFa8IHCVgz2pzb-7Vvx4A1Wci2h2Nw4v6oT0Ao0WaF6-2gOOH67zl6So2vtdsMQEmvZjzaD~r5qaBkGJVWsSehBofiAUm2hg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI6TU7MMXM5DG6EPQ"
}
```

***For Track Details:***

```
{
  "kind": "track",
  "id": 1142143435,
  "created_at": "2021/10/15 07:30:27 +0000",
  "duration": 182831,
  "commentable": true,
  "comment_count": 0,
  "sharing": "public",
  "tag_list": " ",
  "streamable": true,
  "embeddable_by": "all",
  "purchase_url": null,
  "purchase_title": null,
  "genre": "",
  "title": "Track Name",
  "description": "",
  "label_name": null,
  "release": null,
  "key_signature": null,
  "isrc": null,
  "bpm": null,
  "release_year": null,
  "release_month": null,
  "release_day": null,
  "license": "all-rights-reserved",
  "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/114214343435",
  "user": {
    "avatar_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/avatars-00014682366551-2cgqxk-large.jpg",
    "id": 154405051,
    "kind": "user",
    "permalink_url": "https://soundcloud.com/account_name",
    "uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/15440503451",
    "username": "User Name",
    "permalink": "User Name",
    "created_at": "2015/05/23 06:34:12 +0000",
    "last_modified": "2018/11/21 10:41:15 +0000",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "full_name": "",
    "city": null,
    "description": "Om Tamil Calendar for your Android device! \nThis is the perfect and useful application to all Tamil speaking people & Tamil lovers!",
    "country": null,
    "track_count": 1030,
    "public_favorites_count": 0,
    "reposts_count": 0,
    "followers_count": 0,
    "followings_count": 0,
    "plan": "Pro Unlimited",
    "myspace_name": null,
    "discogs_name": null,
    "website_title": null,
    "website": null,
    "comments_count": 0,
    "online": false,
    "likes_count": 0,
    "playlist_count": 25,
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "product": {
          "id": "creator-pro-unlimited",
          "name": "Pro Unlimited"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "permalink_url": "https://soundcloud.com/account_name/track_name",
  "artwork_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-mMD5y9whMs3dyjarz-pTLUjw-lsarge.jpg",
  "stream_url": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/11421843435/stream",
  "download_url": null,
  "waveform_url": "https://wave.sndcdn.com/GTbktMdfIdZVGG_m.png",
  "available_country_codes": null,
  "secret_uri": null,
  "user_favorite": null,
  "user_playback_count": null,
  "playback_count": 30,
  "download_count": 0,
  "favoritings_count": 0,
  "reposts_count": 0,
  "downloadable": false,
  "access": "playable",
  "policy": null,
  "monetization_model": null
}
```

**Download Script for Stream URL;**

```
<?php
    
    $soundcloudURL = 'SOUNDCLOUD_STREAM_URL';
    $fileName = 'audio_1.mp3';
    header("Cache-Control: private");
    header("Content-type: audio/mpeg3");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
    //So the browser can display the download progress
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($soundcloudURL));
    
    readfile($soundcloudURL);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. And how do you keep track for how long access_token is valid?  And do you use refresh_token at all?

Comment: The access token expiration is 3600 secs only. and currently i am not using refresh token?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to download the track if track has download_url?

Comment: Do you want to know if the audio track is downloaded programmatically or manually? You can easily download manually using a browser. I'm using PHP to automate downloads.

Comment: I would like to get download track url. Can you share the code to download track?

Comment: yes shared https://stackoverflow.com/a/69672979/9596361

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me. Are you sure you use SOUNDCLOUD_STREAM_URL?

Comment: have you generated your stream url??

Comment: have you generated your stream url??

Comment: Yes, I can stream successfully but when I try to download it with your code nothing happens. How do you call this php code on your side? I am using ajax.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me still a 401 response. Maybe there are steps which are missing